# Piping of RxJs Operators

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, rxjs

I try to learn RxJs. I want to use it to drag-and-drop objects. I managed to do so. But I'm creating the following `drag$` Observable:

```
const drag$ = mousedown$.pipe(
      switchMap((start) => {
        return merge(
          mousemove$.pipe(
            map((move) => {
              move.preventDefault();
              return {
                type: "move",
                x: move.x - start.x,
                y: move.y - start.y,
              };
            }),
            takeUntil(mouseup$)
          ),
          mouseup$.pipe(
            map((endPos) => {
              return {
                type: "end",
                x: endPos.clientX,
                y: endPos.clientY,
              };
            }),
            take(1)
          )
        );
      })
    );
```

What bothers me, is that I apply the `merge` Operator as an operator receiving two Observables as arguments. Is there an elegant way to redefine the same `drag$` Operator while performing the merge within a pipe?

Comment: Don't be bothered. `merge` needs two observables, so it's natural to pass them as arguments.

Comment: Not necessarily. Look at the code of Example 2 here: https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/merge

Comment: @Achim that is [deprecated](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/merge).

Comment: Ah, okay! Good to know! Thank you!

Comment: For sure. Be careful of tutorial sites

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can use the [`mergeWith` operator](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/operators/mergeWith.ts) (available since RxJS 7.x AFAIK):

```js
const drag$ = mousedown$.pipe(
  switchMap((start) =>
    mousemove$.pipe(
      map((move) => {
        move.preventDefault();
        return {
          type: "move",
          x: move.x - start.x,
          y: move.y - start.y,
        };
      }),
      takeUntil(mouseup$),
      mergeWith(
        mouseup$.pipe(
          map((endPos) => {
            return {
              type: "end",
              x: endPos.clientX,
              y: endPos.clientY,
            };
          }),
          take(1)
        )
      )
    )
  )
);
```

Comment: Not sure: the `mousemove$` pipe terminates with the `mouseup$` event, correct? It is important for me that the resulting `drag$` observable emits the final `mouseup$` event, too.

Comment: And is RxJS 7.x still a beta? I install RxJs using yarn, but it is version 6.6.3.

Comment: I'd say yes. But notice that `mouseup$` observable will be subscribed twice. The functionality should be the same as the one from your snippet. And yeah.. it looks like RxJS 7.x is `beta.9`.

Comment: Ah! Is there a way to obtain the same Operator while subscribing only once to `mouseup$`?

Comment: You could do something like this(before the entire stream): `mouseup$ = mouseup$.pipe(share())`. This will subscribe only once to the main source, but `share()` will add a `Subject` instance in between and that subject will have 2 observers. But the source is still subscribed once.

Comment: Is it problematic if I subscribe twice to the same source?

Comment: It depends, sometimes yes. In this case I'd say it's not very problematic, but you're creating 2 event listeners, where 1 would be enough.